# How orphan objects get created in content and configuration database?

Tags: 2010, content-database, orphan

I searched so many sites but not able to find the reason of creation of orphan objects in content and configuration database.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are many reasons for a object to become Orphan.

- if you delete a user from the AD but that user still present in SharePoint, now this user is called Orphan.
- You are trying to provision a Site collection and their is interruption during the provision process, now that site collection will become orphan.
- You deploy the a feature/solution then later retract it but did not follow the process, then that feature become orphan on the site collection where it is activated.
- You trying to restore a site collection but operation interrupted, later you try again but it fails. Now you have Orphan site in your database.
- In many case, when a content database corrupted, it casue a lot of orphan objects in the DB.
- In many cases, why things become orphan always mystery.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263282(v=office.12).aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2014/03/23/detect-content-db-orphans-in-a-sharepoint-2010-farm-thru-windows-powershell-updated.aspx